# Best scripting tool to profile a log file

Tags: perl, shell, logging, cygwin

I have extracted log files from servers based on my date and time requirement and after extraction it has hundreds of HTTP requests (URLs). Each request may or may not contain various parameters a,b,c,d,e,f,g etc.,

For example:

```
http:///abcd.com/blah/blah/blah%20a=10&b=20ORC
http:///abcd.com/blah/blah/blahsomeotherword%20a=30&b=40ORC%26D
http:///abcd.com/blah/blah/blahORsomeORANDworda=30%20b=40%20C%26D
http:///abcd.com/blah/blah/"blah"%20b=40ORCANDD%20G%20F
```

I wrote a shell script to profile this log file in a while loop, grep for different parameters a,b,c,d,e. If they contain respective parameter then what is the value for that parameter, or TRUE or FALSE.

```
while read line ; do
    echo -n -e $line | sed 's/^.*XYZ:/ /;s/ms.*//' >> output.txt
    echo -n -e "\t" >> output.txt
    echo -n -e $line | sed 's/^.*XYZ:/ /;s/ABC.*//' >> output.txt
    echo -n -e "\t" >> output.txt
    echo -n -e $line | sed 's/^.*?q=/ /;s/AUTH_TYPE:.*//'>> output.txt
    echo -n -e "\t" >> output.txt
    echo " " >> output.txt
done < queries.csv
```

My question is, my cygwin is taking lot of time (an hour or so) to execute on a log file containing 70k-80k requests. Is there a best way to write this script so that it executes asap? I'm okay with perl too. But my concern is, the script is flexible enough to execute and extract parameters.

Comment: Please provide the text of your script instead of a screen shot.  A shell loop like that is extremely inefficient, but this looks like it could be very easily done in a few lines of Awk.

Comment: It would help a lot if you explained the results you wanted in English, rather than have us reverse-engineer your requirement from a shell script

Comment: @tripleee: I I have updated my question. Any suggestions please?

Comment: The script you show now is different from the one in your screen shot before.  Not hugely different, but you were looking for AND and OR and the number of occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

Like @reinerpost already pointed out, the loop-internal redirection is probably the #1 killer issue here.  You might be able to reap significant gains already by switching from

```
while read line; do
    something >>file
    something else too >>file
done <input
```

to instead do a single redirection after `done`:

```
while read line; do
    something
    something else too
done <input >file
```

Notice how this also simplifies the loop body, and allows you to overwrite the file when you (re)start the script, instead of separately needing to clean out any old results.  As also suggested by @reinerpost, not hard-coding the output file would also make your script more general; simply print to standard output, and let the invoker decide what to do with the results.  So maybe just remove the redirections altogether.

(Incidentally, you should switch to `read -r` unless you specifically want the shell to interpret backslashes and other slightly weird legacy behavior.)

Additionally, collecting results and doing a single `print` at the end would probably be a lot more efficient than the repeated unbuffered `echo -n -e` writes.  (And again, `printf` would probably be preferrable to `echo` for both portability and usability reasons.)

The current script could be reimplemented in `sed` quite easily. You collect portions of the input URL and write each segment to a separate field.  This is easily done in `sed` with the following logic: Save the input to the hold space.  Swap the hold space and the current pattern space, perform the substitution you want, append to the hold space, and swap back the input into the pattern space.  Repeat as necessary.

Because your earlier script was somewhat more involved, I'm suggesting to use Awk instead.  Here is a crude skeleton for doing things you seem to be wanting to do with your data.

```
awk '# Make output tab-delimited
    BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
    { xyz_ms = $0; sub("^.*XYX:", " ", xyz_ms); sub("ms.*$", "", xyz_ms);
      xyz_abc = $0; sub("^.*XYZ:", " ", xyz_abc); sub("ABC.*$", "", xyz_abc);
      q = $0; sub("^.*?q=", " ", q); sub("AUTH_TYPE:.*$", "", q);
      # ....
      # Demonstration of how to count something
      n = split($0, _, "&"); ampersand_count = n-1;
      # ...
      # Done: Now print
      print xyz_mx, xyz_abc, q, " " }' queries.csv
```

Notice how we collect stuff in variables and print only at the end.  This is less crucial here than it would have been in your earlier shell script, though.

The big savings here is avoiding to spawn a large number of subprocesses for each input line.  Awk is also better optimized for doing this sort of processing quickly.

If Perl is more convenient for you, converting the entire script to Perl should produce similar benefits, and be somewhat more compatible with the `sed`-centric syntax you have already.  Perl is bigger and sometimes slower than Awk, but in the grand scheme of things, not by much.  If you really need to optimize, do both and measure.

Comment: I'm also holding back on doing a Perl version because your question looks too much like "write this in Perl please" and this is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 0):

Problems with your script:

1. The main problem: you append to a file in every statement. This means the file has to be opened and closed in every statement, which is extremely inefficient.
2. You hardcode the name of the output file in your script. This is a bad practice. Your script will be much more versatile if it just writes its output to stdout. Leave it to the call to specify where to direct the output. That will also get rid of the previous problem.
3. `bash` is interpreted and not optimized for text manipulation: it is bound to be slow, and complex text filtering won't be very readable. Using `awk` instead will probably make it more concise and more readable (once you know the language); however, if you don't know it yet, I advise learning Perl instead, which is good at what `awk` is good at but is also general-purpose language: it makes you much far more flexible, allows you to make it even more readable (those who complain about Perl being hard to read have never seen nontrivial shell scripts), and probably makes it a lot faster, because `perl` compiles scripts prior to running them.  If you'd rather invest your efforts into a more popular language than Perl, try Python.